# Can I redirect away from WSO2 Identity Server Authtication Page

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I am using SAML SSO to authenticate users coming to my web app. I am using the SAML SSO filter. In the login page of IS(AuthenticationEndpoint/samlsso) can I add a button to visit my web page anonymously without authentication? Who should I do the redirection?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add button to login page where you can enter credential to authenticate the user. To get this done you will have to customize authenticationendpoint.war adding new button to the login.jsp page[1] to redirect it to your page.

[1] https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/platform/branches/turing/components/identity/org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.endpoint/4.2.2/src/main/webapp/

Comment: I already did that. I have added a button like this,<input type="submit"onclick="window.location='http://example.com/mobile/mobile.jsp?loginRequest=Anonymous';"> What I need is to skip authentication and go to my page if user clicks on this button. Currently it says login failed if user clicks this button!

Comment: As I understood this has to handle in your Application side. In your application by default direct users to your common page and there set a login button. Then only the users who need to login will redirect to the IDP. as I see this is the correct approach

Comment: I am using the SAML SSO Filter provided by the WSO2 Identity Server it self. That is used to redirect unauthenticated users to IS authentication page. URL patterns are used to redirect users. If I show a login page in my app and redirect users there will be two login pages in my app :( What I understood was after clicking the login button in SAML SSO login page users are redirected to a endpoint called commonoauth. That checks the login state of the users and add the user claims as SMAL response. When I redirect away without login in, this prices fails. Is there a way to by pass this?